# OCamlの ; と ;; の違いが分からない

Tags: ocaml

.mlファイルの中のOCamlコードで、以下のようなコードを書いた際、

```
let print_for_print_test str =
  for i = 0 to String.length-1 str do
    print_string(str)
    print_newline()
  done;;
```

3行目に `;` が足りない、という意味のエラーメッセージが出ました。実際に `;` を補えばうまくいったのですが、OCamlでの `;` と `;;` の違いがよく分かりません。よろしければご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 9):

[こちら(ocaml.org)](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/structure_of_ocaml_programs.ja.html#_4) が参考になると思います。

一部を抜粋します。

> ルール1。;;を使うべきときとは、コードのトップレベルにある文を区切るときだ。関数定義の中のときや、他の文のときは、いらない。
>
> ルール3と4は、一重の;についてだ。こいつは、;;とは完全に別物だ。セミコロンひとつの;は、 シークエンスポイントということになっている。言ってみれば、これは、C、C++、Java、Perlのセミコロンひとつと全く同じことである。

---

3行目のみ必要な点については、
4行目はブロックの最後なので `;`が無くても式の終わりがわかりますが、
3行目はそうではないので 式の区切りを示す `;` が必要となります。

Answer (score 3):

仕様を見てみましょう。

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/language.html

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual020.html

Compilation unitsとspecification,definitionを抜粋すると以下のように定義されています。

```
unit-interface ::=  { specification  [;;] } 
unit-implementation ::=  { definition  [;;] }    

specification   ::= val value-name :  typexpr  
    ∣    external value-name :  typexpr =  external-declaration  
    ∣    type-definition  
    ∣    exception constr-decl  
    ∣    class-specification  
    ∣    classtype-definition  
    ∣    module module-name :  module-type  
    ∣    module module-name  { ( module-name :  module-type ) } :  module-type  
    ∣    module type modtype-name  
    ∣    module type modtype-name =  module-type  
    ∣    open module-path  
    ∣    include module-type  

definition  ::= let [rec] let-binding   { and let-binding }  
    ∣    external value-name :  typexpr =  external-declaration  
    ∣    type-definition  
    ∣    exception-definition  
    ∣    class-definition  
    ∣    classtype-definition  
    ∣    module module-name  { ( module-name :  module-type ) }  [ : module-type ]  =  module-expr  
    ∣    module type modtype-name =  module-type  
    ∣    open module-path  
    ∣    include module-expr
```

OCamlには定義と仕様(まとめて文と呼ぶ)と式の３つがあり、文の区切りには;;を使い、;は式を連続して記述する事に使うと覚えると良さそうです。;;は省略可能ですが、トップレベルや必要なときに使います。

let a = 1は定義で、
val a:intが仕様で、
let b = 1 in bは式です。

```
let a = ();();();1;;
```

はaに1を定義しています。
文として式を書く事も出来るのでトップレベルに式を並べて

```
1;;
2;;
let b = 1 in b;;
3
```

のように書く事も出来ます。
式を文として連続して書くような場合は;;を書く必要があります。

```
f
1
```

と書くとOCamlでは改行は意味を持たないのでf関数に引数1を適用する意味になります。